# YouTube API - Can SSL prevent against spoofing?

Tags: javascript, security, ssl, youtube

So I'm building an application that hits the YouTube API.  The problem is that the application will be in JavaScript, which means that the API key will be publicly visible.

In the YouTube console, I can set access to the API so that API calls are only allowed from certain domains.  I've read online that this "security measure" can be bypassed by spoofing the domain name.

I have verified this by changing the host file on my local machine and connecting to the API, I was successful (unfortuantely).  However, I am able to specify the domain name in the YouTube console using the full URL, INCLUDING HTTPS.

My question is, if I use HTTPS in the URL of the allowed domain, will this prevent against spoofing?